# Cant start pip to install virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

Im trying to use pip to install virtualenv for python 3.0. I figured out how to download pip and i have a file named get-pip on my desktop only problem is I thought it was going to open a console so i could type in a command to download virtualenv instead a console pops up and goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use pip to install something, you either need to direct to the python  /scripts folder and open cmd there **OR** Set a environmental path.

So to find the /Scripts folder under python, you'll need to open the python IDLE and type the following:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

This will return a string of the path of python under your python folder. Direct to that folder and under /scripts press **Shift + RMB**, and then select *Open command window here*. Now try to install virtualenv by typing:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

This should successfully install virtualenv for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help